# Bazaar repository got broken by moving it

Tags: directory, branch, odoo, rename, bazaar

I've gotten the OpenERP source using [the instructions](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/01_getting_started/#installation-from-sources).

I've moved the whole `source` directory somewhere else in my `home`.

Now, when I try to `pull` changes it throws errors:

```
shahar@shahar-desktop:~/src/openerp⟫ make pull
# update all trunk branch
for i in addons client oldweb web server; do [ -d $i ] && (cd $i && bzr pull && cd ..); done
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/shahar/src/openerp/addons/.bzr/branches/origin/trunk/
/".
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/shahar/src/openerp/client/.bzr/branches/origin/trunk/
/".
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/shahar/src/openerp/web/.bzr/branches/origin/trunk/
/".
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/shahar/src/openerp/server/.bzr/branches/origin/trunk/
/".
make: *** [pull] Error 3
2 shahar@shahar-desktop:~/src/openerp⟫
```

It isn't the make script that's at fault:

```
2 shahar@shahar-desktop:~/src/openerp⟫ cd server/
shahar@shahar-desktop:~/src/openerp/server⟫ bzr pull
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/shahar/src/openerp/server/.bzr/branches/origin/trunk/
/".
3 shahar@shahar-desktop:~/src/openerp/server⟫
```

The paths that are printed above seem to be stemming from each repository's `.bzr/branch/location` file.

I've discovered this file when I tried to fix this issue by using `grep -rI /home/shahar`. And then I've changed the path within this file from what it was to what you see now. I thought that it could perhaps fix the issue but it didn't. I still got the same errors (with the new paths).

I couldn't find any info about moving bzr repositories <strike>in the whole of the interwebs</strike> with Google or in StackOverflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installation script you used seems to use the [bzr-colo](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/colo-plugin.html) plugin to manage colocated branches.
The `bzr-colo` manual indicates that because absolute pathnames are used to store references to branches, when a colocated workspace is moved on disk, the link from the checkout to the current branch gets broken.
This can theoretically be fixed by running `bzr colo-fixup` in the broken branch directory, however it does not seem work very often (in my experience).

In that case the [manual](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/colo-plugin.html#colo-fixup) recommends running this command to re-force a branch switch:

```
    bzr switch --force .bzr/branches/<current branch name>
```

According to the output of your commands, this should be:

```
    bzr switch --force .bzr/branches/origin/trunk
```

for you.

You do not even need to edit the `.bzr/branch/location` first, as it will be correct after the switch. This has always fixed the situation for me.